# Row colour change based on text in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

How do I change the whole row's colour if one of the cells (C3) is "YES", then also the same row a second colour if that cell is "no", a third colour if that cell is "maybe" and then no colour if nothing is in that cell?

Comment: What do you mean by, "a row's colour"? The font color? Shading? Border color?

Comment: look into conditional formatting

Answer (score 3):

Select the whole worksheet, Go to Home > Conditional Formatting.
Choose New Rule. Formula type choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
In the Rule type `=$C1="NO"` assuming that column `C` contains the value, then press Format and choose your formatting options.
Repeat New Rule for Yes and Maybe.

[image: See Image]

Answer (score 1):

Is the Cell C3 fixed in your sample?

This is a sample if you only need to confirm value in column C for Row 3:

*"Yes" color: Red*

*"No" color: Yellow*

*"Maybe" color: Blue*

Set 3 rules from Row 3 with formula:

**=$C$3="Yes"**

**=$C$3="No"**

**=$C$3="Maybe"**

[image]